# Probability distributions and float variables, probability must add to 1

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, distribution, probability

I'm working on a script which goes like this: the program analyses a bunch of text documents in a certain language, draws the probability distributions for each k, where k is the first character appearing after each given letter of the alphabet in each word of the text. Then the program uses this knowledge to try and write "real" words using Markov Chains.

I have already written most of the script, and it is already spitting out interesting words, the point is that the function which generates words is working with a try and except mechanism to avoid getting stuck. It gets stuck because some probability distributions DO NOT add to 1 (I guess becuase the float type is not that precise or something like that) and the numpy functions which should work with these distributions raises a ValueError because of the probabilities not adding up to 1.

By triggering the exception for some distributions, some words are not generated at all and the final result is less interesting than what it might be.

Now, my question is: is there a way to make these probability distributions add up to 1 when they are generated?
I've tried gmpy2, the round() function but no one seems to work. Maybe this is a silly question and I just need to get some fresh air... Anyway, some help would be useful!

here is the code for the generation of the probability distribution

```
def FreqRel(self,listValues):
    absFreq = self.AbsFreq(listValues)
    freqRel = []
    for i in absFreq:
        freqRel.append(i/sum(absFreq))
    if sum(freqRel) != 1:
        print("Frequencies do not add up to 1")
        if sum(freqRel) - 1 < 0:
            diff = sum(freqRel) - 1
            #This should be an adjustment which should not interfere
            #that much on the probability distribution
            freqRel[1] = freqRel[1] - diff
            print("missing",diff)
        elif sum(freqRel) - 1 > 0:
            diff = sum(freqRel) - 1
            #This should be an adjustment which should not interfere
            #that much on the probability distribution
            freqRel[1] = freqRel[1] - diff
            print("Too much",diff)
    return freqRel
```

Here is what I get printed on the console when running this function:
[image]

[image]

Here is the code that crashes when the sum is not 1. The numpy lines are thos which crash.
and the error is: ValueError: probabilities do not add up to 1.

```
def spitText(n):
    i = 0
    while i < n:
        try:
            word = ""
            #This oldChar setting is arbitrary, later I'm going to fix it
            oldChar = "b"
            for k in range(np.random.choice(distributions[0],replace=True,p=distributions[1])):
                newChar = np.random.choice(alphabet,replace=True,p=distRel[alphabet.index(oldChar)])
                word = word + newChar
                oldChar = newChar
            print(word)
            time.sleep(0.2)
            i+=1
        except:
            pass
```

Comment: What is your `freqAss`? Where does it originate from?

Comment: Sorry, it should be absFreq instead of freqAss. That's a typo. Just edited, thanks!

Comment: Can you show us the code that crashes when the sum is not 1?

Comment: It's perfectly reasonable—and unavoidable—to expect a rounding error on the order of 1e-17, unless all of your probabilities happen to be exact binary fractions. That's how floats work. You can't solve this by getting rid of the rounding error; you can only solve it by changing your code to deal with that rounding error in some reasonable way. Since you haven't shown us the relevant code, we can't show you how to change it.

Comment: Just added. The numpy part is the one that crashes.. and the error is: ValueError: probabilities do not add up to 1.

Comment: Do you know what `1e-17` means? This is a little less than nothing and probably caused by floating point precision. I suggest you just check whether the difference is below some very low threshold, say `1e-10`, and ignore differences that are smaller than that. Alternatively, try working with logarithms (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25098962/1639625)), i.e. instead of multiplying tiny probabilities, add their logs.

Comment: When I run `np.random.choice`, I only get that error if the sum of probabilities is off by -5 orders of relative magnitude. It's perfectly happy with a sum of `1+3e-17`; it's only when you above `1+1e-5` that it complains. So, I'm pretty sure this is not your real data, and you have an actual error somewhere, not just a rounding error.

Comment: Tobias_k, yes I know what that means.. However since my main field of study is not Computer Science I do not have all the necessary knowledge about floats, for instance. Thanks for your suggestion, I'm going to check the link!

Comment: For an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve): `np.random.choice(5, 3, p=[0.4, 0.6+3e-17])` works fine, while `np.random.choice(5, 3, p=[0.4, 0.6+3e-5])` raises.

Comment: abarnert, that's weird, the data is this one, I've just run the script. Anyway, I did not know that feature about numpy, thanks for the advice, I'm going to read through my program and check whether something else is going wrong.

Comment: Where do those `1.0` and `0` outputs come from? You haven't shown any code that prints just a number. Are those sums of frequency distributions by any chance? If so, that's obviously your problem; you can't choose from an empty frequency distribution…

Comment: One last thing: Please don't post screenshots of output, just paste the output as text.

Comment: abarnert, that's a simple for loop outside this function that prints out the sum of each distribution stored as a returned value from this function. About the screenshots, I didn't know that, will keep it in mind the next time, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have some output that looks like this:

```
1.0
1.0
1.0
0
1.0
1.0
```

From a comment:

> that's a simple for loop outside this function that prints out the sum of each distribution stored as a returned value from this function

So, some of your frequency distributions sum to `0`. That's your problem.

Presumably your code that builds the distributions have some edge case that either returns an empty distribution, or one that's all zeros. Either way, it's obviously not going to work.

---

The fact that many of those `1.0` values are off by a cumulative rounding error of as much as 8e-17 is a red herring. You can see that numpy is built to handle those:

```
>>> np.random.choice(2, 3, p=[0.4, 0.6+3e-17])
array([1, 0, 0])
```

It's only when the error gets large enough (the default relative epsilon for most of numpy is 1e-5) that it complains:

```
>>> np.random.choice(2, 3, p=[0.4, 0.6+3e-5])
ValueError: probabilities do not sum to 1
```

So you must have some probability distributions whose sums are off of `1` by more than `1e-5`. And of course you do; you have some that are off by a whole `1`.

---

This means your main question:

> is there a way to make these probability distributions add up to 1 when they are generated?

… is really an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem): it's not the thing you need to solve here.

But I'll answer it anyway. The short answer is: No. Floats are binary fractions with a fixed number of digits of precision. If you try to store arbitrary real numbers in floats, you will get rounding errors. You can see this pretty easily:

```
>>> 1.0 + 1e-17
1.0
```

There just aren't enough bits to store `1.0` and `1.00000000000000001` as different binary fractions.

If you want to understand further (and you should), read [What every computer scientist should know about floating point](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html), the classic introductory paper on the topic.

Comment: That's it! Some letters do not appear at all, therefore their distributions sum to 0 causing the error when sampled. I suspected it was something silly... Thanks abarnert! I will check out the paper!

Comment: @mickkk: I figured something like that. Most bugs are caused by simple edge cases that you never think of in advance, but that are obvious once you know to look for them. (Well, that, and stupid typos that I can't see in my own code no matter how hard I stare at it…) Aren't you glad computer science isn't your main field? :)

Comment: +1 Great catch! @mickkk: You could try [Laplace Smoothing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_smoothing) to fix this.

Comment: @abarnert: for that matter: yes :) however, the fact that CS is so useful and fascinating makes those annoying "problems" totally bearable even for a newbie like me :)